# Poltergeist Stripe checkout.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, stripe-payments, poltergeist

I'm trying to test in my Rails app the Stripe checkout popup (http://www.stripe.com/checkout).

I was using Capybara + selenium-driver and everything worked well.
When the page is loaded, the checkout.js adds an iframe, and I was able to access it

```
within_frame('stripe_checkout_app') do
 do something
end
```

Now, switching to Poltergeist, I get this error:

> Failure/Error: within_frame('stripe_checkout_app') do
>        Capybara::Poltergeist::FrameNotFound:
>          The frame 'stripe_checkout_app' was not found.

and if I inspect the page, there's not iframe. So I think that this script

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>`

is not loaded when I run the test with Poltergeist.

Update

I tried to run the test with Capybara-webkit, with same result.

```
Failure/Error: Capybara.within_frame('stripe_checkout_app') do
 Capybara::Webkit::InvalidResponseError:
   Unable to locate frame.
```

I also tried to wait for half a minute! with

```
sleep 30
```

These are my webmock settings:

```
RSpec.configure { |config|
WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow_localhost: true)
 }
```

Update 2:

'stripe_checkout_app' is the name of the iframe.

```
<iframe frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" src="https://checkout.stripe.com/v3" name="stripe_checkout_app" class="stripe_checkout_app" style="z-index: 9999; display: none; background-color: transparent; border: 0px none transparent; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto; visibility: visible; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For anybody interested, I found a way to access the iframe without using 'within_frame', just by using the Poltergeist switch window method.

```
stripe = page.driver.window_handles.last

page.within_window stripe do
  fill_in "Name", :with => "Name"
  fill_in "Street", :with => "Street"
  fill_in "Postal", :with => 10000
  fill_in "City", :with => "Berlin"

  click_button "Payment Info"
end
```

For spanish people, I found the solution here: [numerica latina](http://www.numerica.cl/2014/02/debugear-webkit-como-driver-de-capybara/).

Comment: parov, I have the same problem ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081305 ) though when I try your solution I get the following error: `undefined method 'window_handles' for #<Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver:0x007fa09adde108>` - any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: can you check which branch of poltergeist are you using? The method is there in the master branch. https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist/blob/master/lib/capybara/poltergeist/browser.rb

Comment: Thanks parov! You lead me down the correct path! When I `bundle update` I get `Using poltergeist (1.0.3)`, which seemed pretty old. ... inspecting my gemfile shows I had locked Capybara to '~>1.1.2' which limited Poltergeist to 1.0.3. Updating everything to the latest gems (Capybara 2.3.0 & Poltergeist 1.5.1) fixed everything!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a similar issue with `phantomjs 1.9.7`, it's because of the SSL settings. You can disable checking using:

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  options = {
    phantomjs_options: ['--ssl-protocol=any', '--ignore-ssl-errors=yes'],
    inspector: false
  }
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, options)
end
```